Coordinate-wise iterative minimization based on partial derivatives
Frequently in competition programming problems, the task is to minimize a function with a simple closed form of sequence of values, such as
$$\min f(\mathbf x) = \min e^{-x_0} x_1 + e^{-x_1} x_2 + e^{-x_2} x_3 + \cdots + e^{-x_{N-1}} x_N$$
where $x_0$ and $x_N$ are constrained to be some boundary value, say 0 and a big number.
One technique that works often is setting each partial derivative to zero, say
$$0 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = e^{-x_{i-1}} - e^{-x_i}x_{i+1}$$
solving for each coordinate $x_i$ in terms of its neighbors, then iteratively updating the coordinates in order $x_1, \dots, x_{N-1}$.
Does this optimization technique have a name? Is it iterative relaxation or coordinate descent based on gradient? Bear in mind I know next to nothing about differential equations - this is just an algorithm I've seen that somehow works.

Minimising each coordinate (or some approximation thereof) cyclically is coordinate wise descent. It is not clear what differential equation you are referring to. The $\min$ of the abve problem is zero, of course.

@copper.hat I do not think the min is zero given boundary x_N is set to be a large value, say 100. If the initial points are set reasonably then the solution will be an increasing sequence of numbers from 0 to 100

The differential equation I guess is simply the gradient is 0, so all the partial derivatives are 0. I guess then solving each coordinate while holding the others constant counts as coordinate descent.
